# Android: Different APK for different hardware

Tags: android

Is there a way in android to publish different APKs based on various heuristics such as

1. Total available memory
2. CPU speed/type
3. Storage space
4. Even brand name (Samsung or Nexus or whatever)

I know there's a way to do it for different screens but let's say you would like to have more animations and better resolution images and more graphic/CPU intensive operations for higher end phones and tablets but still provide basic level functionality (albeit with reduced function set or a more basic UI) for older/less powerful phones.

Is this possible? If not, I fear I have to cater for the lowest end of the market and won't be able to make use of the better hardware that some users may be using.

Many thanks,

p.s. I'd seen this before I posted my question http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html but it doesn't quite answer this question which is why I posted my question.

Why it doesn't answer my question is because it only mentions the following attributes for determining which APK would be available for a device:

- OpenGL texture compression formats
- Screen size (and, optionally, screen density)
- Device feature sets
- API level
- CPU architecture (ABI)

However, it does not mention the memory, storage space or the CPU speed (though CPU architecture may... I have no idea) which would be ideal to have to decide whether or not to load a reduced set of resources and functionality or not which is why I don't believe the mentioned link quite answers my question.

Comment: I have a vague feeling it is, but it's generally considered extremely unwise to have different APKs for different setups unless your APK is **huge**. Instead make the app decide at runtime whether to use high end graphics/efficiency graphics etc. So cater for the high end and downgrade as necissary at runtime (of course android helps you with this with the way it organises resources)

Comment: Where you have found a specific resource that appears to answer your question but doesn't its generally a good idea to specify how it doesn't answer your question

Comment: Ok I'll add why it doesn't.